# Typo doesn't wanna link on ios and android project

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

i add my font on a file react-native.config.js like that :

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/font'],
};
```

then i npx react-native Link , the typo are adding on my ios and android files but they don't reconized my typo on IOS and android when i put it like :

```
fontFamily:'Ambit-Black'
```

i have this error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `assets: ['./assets/font']` to `assets: ['./assets/fonts']`

Comment: It's working with android now but not with ios even if the typo is register on Xcode